# How do I specify utf8mb4 for a mySQL column in web2py?

Tags: mysql, unicode, web2py

In web2py, how do I make sure that a column of type='string' uses the full 4-byte unicode format (utf8mb4) when creating tables in a mySQL database?

Comment: you specify it at the database, table or column level during creation. At the table level it comes after the ending `)` with a `collate=` or a `charset=`. At the column-level it naturally occurs inside the create table statement.

Comment: If you just specify `collate=` then mysql will map it to the charset that rules for it. Manual page here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html

Comment: Useful, thanks. Not sure how this is done in web2py, though. The Field() constructor doesn't take a 'collate' option http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor

Comment: idk but look at http://i.imgur.com/Q3fjRpD.jpg ... the `db_codec`

Comment: @Drew - thanks. Annoyingly that doesn't seem to do anything. This forum post implies it might be a problem, but it's from a few years back: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/PHp25xAL-fI

Comment: I will ping someone I know

Comment: I guess it might be possible to set globally using driver={} or adapter={} args when constructing the DAL

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify what @Drew pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the web2py side, you can specify the encoding via the `set_encoding` parameter in the connection string:

```
db = DAL('mysql://username:password@localhost/test?set_encoding=utf8mb4')
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried changing the string in appconfig.ini by appending "?set_encoding=utf8mb4" to the uri param, but then I get "gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 891, in _get_server_information self.server_version = data[i:server_end].decode(self.charset) LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8mb4" even though I have utf8mb4 defined in pymysql/charset.py. If I did get it to work, would this cause the table creation / migration commands to default to proper unicode?