# How do I insert 4 byte unicode chars using web2py (mySQL)?

Tags: mysql, unicode, web2py

I have a mySQL table which is set to CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 and a column x which has CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and I can run an SQL command directly on the database which inserts a 4-byte unicode character, like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (x) VALUES ('');
```

but when I run the following in web2py, I get a different entry, which looks like `????`

```
sql = u"INSERT INTO mytable (x) VALUES (%s)"
db.executesql(sql, (u'',))
```

Is there something I need to set in web2py somewhere to tell it to pass the unicode characters through without alteration?

Addendum: the same `????` entry occurs when I use the DAL too, as in

```
db.mytable.insert(x=u'')
```

Comment: Update - I get the following in the logs `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:165: Warning: (1300, u"Invalid utf8 character string: 'F09F92'")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:165: Warning: (1366, u"Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\xA9' for column 'search_string' at row 1")` . My pyMySQL is the most recent, 0.8.0.

Comment: Also, it *does* work if I use pyMySQL on its own (i.e. not via Web2Py)

Comment: I have reported this as a bug at https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1838 - I hope that's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "question mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

See Python notes in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python .  In particular, what are your connection parameters (between Python and MySQL)?

`u"Invalid utf8 character string: 'F09F92'"` implies that Python (perhaps from interpreting a MySQL `utf8` error) is baffled by the 4-byte pile of poo.

Comment: really helpful pointers, thanks. The odd thing here is that it works using python and pymysql from the command-line, but not from within web2py, which is why I reported it as a bug on the web2py github site. I will check the connection parameters.

Comment: So in the web2py DAL, it doesn't make any difference if I set DAL(db_codec="utf8mb4"...), but it *does* work if I specify the connection parameters in the string that defined the DB, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349972/how-do-i-specify-utf8mb4-for-a-mysql-column-in-web2py. That now works, thanks!

Comment: @user2667066 - Oops, I the DAL farther down in my second link; I failed to look for "web2py".